Make a letter as big as the div
I'm having difficulties make the concrete thing in CSS as I wish.
My goal is to create a Letter in this case the letter K and make it as big as the div container it is in.
Here is the code snippet:
I included some further code because I want to then include text next to it.
The picture added shows how I would want the K to be placed with the top and bottom just inside the container. (it may be important to add that it's in located in a carousel). It would be important to me that the solution is responsive. I would appreciate every support.


<div class="carousel-item active">
  <div class="container-fluid" style="background-color: #D65A31; height: max(40vh,30vw);">
    <div class="row h-100" style="line-height: 1;">
      <div class="col-4 d-flex flex-column justify-content-center">
        <span style="color: #2BB673; font-size: max(40vh,30vw);display: flex; text-align: center;">K</span>
      </div>
      <div class="col-8 d-flex flex-column justify-content-center">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
            <p style="font-size: 7vw; z-index: 1; color: #EEEEEE;">Lorem.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
            <p style="font-size: 3vw; opacity: 75%; color: #EEEEEE;">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



I already tried adjusting the size of the letter, but it usually destroyed the "layout" I had in mind and expanded the carousels size in an unwanted way. K bordering the div as wanted

Fonts are complicated, so it not very easy to use them in the way you want. Have a look at this typeface anatomy. Notice how there are guiding lines, but the font doesn't quite stick to them. Basically what you want cannot be done with CSS. It can be done by other means, for instance by using an image. There's nothing wrong with an image, because a font is, in the end, also just an image.

This is complicated by the fact that the letter k has no descender but the font is likely to save space below for a possible descender. The only way I’ve been absolutely sure of creating a character and knowing where its top and bottom limits are is to draw it on a canvas and inspect the pixels.

@KIKOSoftware Thank you for clearing up my assumption. At least I'm now sure that I should look at the other ways

You could also replace the HTML text element with a <SVG> that would behave similar to an <img> element.


//approximate a tight bounding box via canvas measure text
let bb = getTextBB(text)
console.log(bb)


function getTextBB(textEl) {
  let style = window.getComputedStyle(textEl);
  let text = textEl.textContent;
  let svg = textEl.closest("svg");

  let {
    fontFamily,
    fontSize,
    fontWeight,
    fontStyle
  } = style;
  fontSize = parseFloat(fontSize);
  let {
    x,
    y,
    ascender,
    descender,
    width,
    height
  } = getTextMetrics(
    text,
    fontFamily,
    fontSize,
    fontWeight,
    fontStyle
  );

  // text el bbox
  let bb = textEl.getBBox();

  let bbTight = {
    x: bb.x + x,
    y: bb.y + y,
    width: width,
    height: height
  };

  return bbTight;
}

function getTextMetrics(
  text,
  fontFamily = "Arial",
  fontSize = 1000,
  fontWeight = 400,
  fontStyle = "normal"
) {
  //ignore whitespace
  text = text.trim();

  // create temporary canvas
  let canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  let context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  // scale for more precise values
  let scale = fontSize < 100 ? 1000 / fontSize : 1;
  //scale = 10


  //render text
  context.font = `${fontWeight} ${fontStyle} ${
    fontSize * scale
  }px ${fontFamily}`;
  let metrics = context.measureText(text);
  let left = metrics.actualBoundingBoxLeft;
  let right = metrics.actualBoundingBoxRight;
  let width = right + left;
  //let width = metrics.width;
  let ascender = metrics.actualBoundingBoxAscent;
  let descender = metrics.actualBoundingBoxDescent;
  let height = ascender + descender;
  //tight y bb offset
  let yOffset = metrics.fontBoundingBoxAscent - ascender;


  let textMetrics = {
    x: -(left / scale),
    y: yOffset / scale,
    width: width / scale,
    height: height / scale,
    ascender: ascender / scale,
    descender: descender / scale
  };

  canvas.remove();
  return textMetrics;
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

svg {
  display: block;
  overflow: visible;
  height: 100%;
}

.wrap {
  background-color: #d65a31;
  height: 50vmin;
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
  outline: 1px solid #ccc;
}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Fira+Sans:ital,wght@0,400;0,700;1,400;1,700&display=swap">

<h3>Resize me</h3>
<div class="wrap" style="color: #2BB673;">
  <svg viewBox="10 0 48.9 68">
    <text id="text" fill="currentColor" font-size="100" font-family="Fira Sans" x="0" y="100%">K</text>
  </svg>
</div>



How it works

we set the SVG text y value to 100% – this way the text's baseline is aligned to the bottom edge of the SVG
we calculate/approximate a suitable "tight" bounding box via canvas measureText() – this way we get x/y offsets as well as height and width values closer to the visible bounding box of the text. We copy these values to the SVG's viewBox attribute.
However, this method is not very accurate – so we should slightly tweak the values. Firefox return more accurate values than Chromium. Once we found suitable values we don't need any JavaScript helper any longer and can save the SVG in HTML (or as a static external asset).
if you choose to load the SVG in an <img> element – you need to embed the font as a dataUrl



* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

svg {
  display: block;
  overflow: visible;
  height: 100%;
}

img{
    height: 100%;
}

.wrap {
  background-color: #d65a31;
  height: 50vmin;
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
  outline: 1px solid #ccc;
}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Fira+Sans:ital,wght@0,400;0,700;1,400;1,700&display=swap">

<h3>Resize me</h3>
<div class="wrap" style="color: #2BB673;">
  <svg viewBox="10 0 48.9 68">
    <text id="text" fill="currentColor" font-size="100" font-family="Fira Sans" x="0" y="100%">K</text>
  </svg>
</div>

<div class="wrap" style="color: #2BB673;">

  <img src="data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='10 0 48.9 68'><style>@font-face {font-family: 'Fira Sans';font-style: normal;font-weight: 400;src: url('data:font/woff2;base64,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') format('woff2');font-display: swap;} </style><text id='text' fill='%232BB673' font-size='100' font-family='Fira Sans' x='0' y='100%'>K</text></svg>" alt="">
</div>




Instead of fighting with a font, use a png image file with the letter K "drawn" in it. You can then set <img> width and height to 100% to fill your containing <div>.


.Container {
  background-color: #D65A31;
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;

  padding: 0rem;
}

.Container img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
<div class="Container">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b9/Latin_Letter_K_with_stroke.png" alt="K">
</div>




Essentially, what you want is the text-box property (longhands: text-box-trim and text-box-edge) but for now only Safari supports it. (Coming soon to Chrome, and hopefully others in the not too distant future.)
You would use it as
text-box: trim-both cap alphabetic;

In your case you'd also need to replace the display:flex on the span with display:block

Could you create code snippet in your answer? I cannot make it work: https://codepen.io/kikosoft/pen/mybRWqK Also note that things like trim-both are currently very poorly supported by most browsers.

@KIKOSoftware -As I said in the answer, it's all poorly supported in most browsers at the moment. Which browser are you testing in? Your codepen works perfectly in Chrome Canary (v133) with text-box support turned on via chrome:flags.

A link to the Can I Use entry for text-box.
